# Installation of MariaDB on Centos 6.5 X86_64

Tags: mariadb

When i am installing MariaDB on Centos 6.5 via "yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client" then server shown the "Transaction Check Error:

`file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64
  file /etc/my.cnf from install of MariaDB-common-10.0.9-1.el6.i686 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.36-1.el6.remi.x86_64`

Error Summary
-------------

" please suggest me for the same.

Answer (score 12):

Had the same problem, for me this is what worked:

run `rpm -qa | grep -i mysql`
which gave me some packages still installed like:

```
MySQL-devel-advanced-5.5.27-1.el6.x86_64
MySQL-shared-advanced-5.5.27-1.el6.x86_64
mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-1.x86_64
MySQL-client-advanced-5.5.27-1.el6.x86_64
```

so

```
yum remove MySQL-devel-advanced-5.5.27-1.el6.x86_64
yum remove ...
```

...you get the point

Answer (score 3):

what's the order you install the MariaDB packages ?

did you remove mysql-libs first ?

rpm -e --nodeps mysql-libs

then try

yum install MariaDB-client MariaDB-common MariaDB-compat MariaDB-devel MariaDB-server MariaDB-shared

You can also install it by running:

```
rpm -ivh MariaDB-*
```

Answer (score 0):

[1] First, you have to remove mysql:

```
    service mysql stop
    yum remove mysql
```

Make sure to remove the directory /var/lib/mysql unless your MySQL version is drop-in compatible with your version of MariaDB. (I would probably still remove it.)

[2] Once mysql is gone, you need to add the appropriate repository to yum. MariaDB offers a configurator of repositories here:

```
    https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
```

It will give you the code you need to put in a file with an extension .repo under /etc/yum.repos.d/

[3] Find out here which exact packages you need for your version of MariaDb:

```
    https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-the-mariadb-rpm-files/
```

You will need MariaDB-compat for MySQL compatibility (including InnoDB support in MariaDB 10.x)

[4] Begin installation:

```
    yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client MariaDB-compat MariaDB-shared
```

[5] First thing you should do after the installation is securing access to it. Run:

```
    mysql_secure_installation
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

maybe you can find one conflict file, and try to redependcy, like this.....

```
rpm -qf /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys
```

I got this package. mariadb-libs-5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64 
After removed this package, maybe you can install MariaDB.

```
yum remove mariadb-libs-5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
```